# Magento 1.9 Wrong customer created and last login dates

Tags: date, admin, magento-1.9

I am running Magento v.1.9.0.1 and I am facing a problem with the dates displayed when editing a customer via the admin area. For example,

Last Logged In: **11 Feb 7791** 4:23:48 μ.μ.
Last Logged In (Europe/Istanbul):   **09 Feb 2015** 3:16:31 μ.μ.
Account Created on: **02 Sep 2015** 4:16:11 μ.μ.

The client registered on the 9th of February 2015. I searched around and found topics about other Magento versions that said for some dates Magento is swapping the dates, hence the difference between actual created date (09/02/2015) and reported created date (02/09/2015).

I couldn't find anything about version 1.9 nor anything about the year reported for last logged in (7791!).

Is there a fix for this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In my experience, there are two things you should try,
1:- Check for the locale of the time that is displayed.
2:- Deactivate recently installed plugins and see the result. Maybe there are some overrides.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I am not sure what to check for the locale. I have chosen Europe/Instanbul, but the problem is not that there is a time difference. The problem is that for some dates Magento is swapping the day and month. Of course, the other problem is that weird 7791 year. I was hoping that a fix could exist, since I have seen many references to that problem, but no fixes specifically for v1.9.

Comment: So, I followed the instructions in [this post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/customer-created-at-date-off-by-months/31225#31225) and I suppose I will just have to monitor the new account creations to see if the Created At dates are correct. Does any of you guys have a clue about the "Last Logged In: 11 Feb 7791" problem?

Comment: If you are still interested, the year 7791 problem is a bug in Magento core code. In some cases they are interpreting a unix timestamp as a datetime string, and things go downhill from there. (It does not always convert to year 7791, the resulting date varies a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue in Magento 1.8.1 , and applied below solution for account created date and last login date.Because some how Magento is converting day to month and month to date in customer edit section.
Path : `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tab\View.php`
Override below methods from above file :

```
    public function getCreateDate()
    {
        $cutomerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $select = $connection->select()
                  ->from('customer_entity', array('created_at'))  
                  ->where('entity_id=?',$cutomerId);    
        $rowArray = $connection->fetchRow($select);        

        return $this->_getCoreHelper()->formatDate($rowArray['created_at'],
            Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
    }

    public function getStoreCreateDate()
    {
        $cutomerId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $select = $connection->select()
                  ->from('customer_entity', array('created_at'))
                  ->where('entity_id=?',$cutomerId);
        $rowArray = $connection->fetchRow($select); 

        return $this->_getCoreHelper()->formatDate($rowArray['created_at'],
            Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
    }

    public function getLastLoginDate()
    {
       if ($date = $this->getCustomerLog()->getLoginAtTimestamp()) {
            $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(
                $this->getCustomer()->getStoreId(),
                $date,
                true
            );
            return $this->formatDate($date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
        }
        return Mage::helper('customer')->__('Never');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue for quite a long time till i found the solution http://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-bug-magento-customer-create-date-juxtaposition/

Summary of the files in the Magento Extension for solving the Magento Date Switch Fix:
Created.php:
app/code/local/CustomerParadigm/Datefix/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time/Created.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 // * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Eav
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Entity/Attribute/Model - attribute backend default
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Eav
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class CustomerParadigm_Datefix_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created
{

    /**
     * Returns date format if it matches a certain mask.
     * @param $date
     * @return null|string
     */
/* This shouldn't be needed for the datetime switch bug fix. Removing for testing.
    protected function _getFormat($date)
    {
        if (is_string($date) && preg_match('#^\d{4,4}-\d{2,2}-\d{2,2} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}$#', $date)) {
            return 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
        }
        return null;
    }
*/

    /**
     * Set created date
     * Set created date in UTC time zone
     *
     * @param Mage_Core_Model_Object $object
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);
        if (is_null($date)) {
            if ($object->isObjectNew()) {
                $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
            }
        } else {
        // Date switch fix
            $date = strtotime($date);

            // convert to UTC
            $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true);
            $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Convert create date from UTC to current store time zone
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created
     */
    public function afterLoad($object)
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);

    // Date switch fix
    if (!is_null($date)) {
        $date = strtotime($date);
    }

        $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(null, $date, true);
        $object->setData($attributeCode, $zendDate->getIso());

        parent::afterLoad($object);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/code/local/CustomerParadigm/Datefix/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <eav>
                <rewrite>
                    <entity_attribute_backend_time_created>CustomerParadigm_Datefix_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created</entity_attribute_backend_time_created>
                </rewrite>
            </eav>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/etc/module/ CustomerParadigm_Datefix.xml

```
<?xml version=”1.0″?>
<config>
<modules>
<CustomerParadigm_Datefix>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</CustomerParadigm_Datefix>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not having much reputation to comment, so pointing out through a response:

@Digisha: You have mentioned this for `getLastLoginDate()`

```
public function getLastLoginDate()
{
    if ($date = $this->getCustomerLog()->getLoginAtTimestamp()) {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(
        $this->getCustomer()->getStoreId(),
        $date,
        true
    );
    return $this->formatDate($date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM, true);
}
return Mage::helper('customer')->__('Never');
}
```

I just want to ask if this is correct parameter for if condition:

```
if ($date = $this->getCustomerLog()->getLoginAtTimestamp())
```

I don't think so, you are assinging and then how is this correct??